# Next JS link is changing given url in href prop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

Currently, in my application, I am using the `next/link` and I am passing the href.

```
href= "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=4720%20S.%20Cottage%20Grove%20Avenue%20Chicago%20IL"

...
...

<Link href={href} as={as} scroll={false}>
      <ClickProxy>{children}</ClickProxy>
</Link>
```

For some reason when we click on the link in the web URL one slash '/' is missing you can look at the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Link` is use for the website which you can manipulate. User can click the `Link` and pass to another page without reload. On the other hand, your `href` is from google, it must cause the reload. I think just using `<a href="..."></a>` is fine.